# angular-ui-router - ng-model not accepting input text change unless in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The problem is:
Using ui-router 0.2.0 and angular 1.1.x, ng-model is not accepting changes to an input text field (I also tried checkbox and select dropdown with same dis-allowed change!).

However, an input text in an ng-repeat does work.

When the view/state loads initially, the values are populated from the model, but after that the problem manifests itself.

**How can I fix the runnable example below to allow changes to the "Serial" input text field using ng-model?**

See this plunker and image below:
(Stetch the plunker preview window to account for poor css)
http://plnkr.co/edit/bS8ZQuiJNG2uE4zuzvyB?p=preview

Problem example image:
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1CQb1SmJqWsWnuG87T0jrhiOTJdXIh3XCqXEINdbvx5c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this is a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410403/using-ng-model-on-a-resolved-promise-in-angularjs-strange-behavior

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using ng-model with a promise.  The solution is to resolve the promise, making the assignment to the $scope.myModel in the then(...) of the promise:

```
var promise = somethingAsyncThatReturnsAPromise();
var itemDeferred = $q.defer();
itemDeferred.promise.then(function(obj) {
  $scope.myModel = obj;
});
itemDeferred.resolve(promise);
```

This question is similar to:
[Using ng-model on a resolved promise in AngularJS (strange behavior)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410403/using-ng-model-on-a-resolved-promise-in-angularjs-strange-behavior)

Here is a fixed, simplified version (angular 1.2.3 + ui-router 0.2.0):
http://plnkr.co/edit/eSQjfBpv1V6Q1WTiDV3N?p=preview

And the fixed original version (angular 1.1.5 + ui-router 0.2.0):
http://plnkr.co/edit/W7nkH8p6HreKcPOnfEq1?p=preview

If there is a more elegant solution, I am interested.